# scrabble issue c++ using vector

Tags: c++

im programming a little scrabble game, here are the code which i prefer to simulate the "playfield", but i got some issue

```
#include "Scrabble.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

Scrabble::Scrabble() {

    Character *pointer;
    pointer = NULL;

    reihe = 15;
    spalte = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < reihe; i++) {
        playground.push_back(vector <Character>());
        for (int j = 0; j < spalte; j++) {
            playground[i].push_back('a');
        }
    }
}

void Scrabble::print() {

    cout << "  ";

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        cout << i << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        cout << r << " ";
        for (int s = 0; s < cloumn; s++) {
            cout << playground[r][s] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;

    }

}`
```

the output looks a little strange

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
0 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a
 a

1 a
 a
```

some advice how i get it looks normal like:

```
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 
    0 a
    1 a
    2 a
    3 a
    4 a
    5 a
    6 a
    7 a
    8 a
    9 a
   10 a
   11 a
   12 a
   13 a
   14 a
```

any advice will be helpful, thx

Comment: please ignorant the NULLpointer, its just an alpha version :)

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet doesn't compile (e.g. variable `cloumn`), so I suppose this is not exactly the code that you are testing.

One problem you'll face, is to ensure the with of a field.  For this you have to include `<iomanip>`:

```
void Scrabble::print() {
    cout<<"   "; 

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
        cout << setw(2)<<i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        cout << setw(2)<< r << " ";
        for (int s = 0; s < column; s++) {
            cout << setw(2)<< playground[r][s] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Here an [online version](http://ideone.com/zMAJ0t) (compiled without class, for demo purpose, as I don't know the definition of `Scrabble`

Comment: +1 for excellent answer with link to your code in ideone.com. @Joe Geoffrey - can you please edit your question to use the exact code that you are testing?